# When config vpn point to site of azure, how to get url of vpn client package

Tags: azure

I configed successfully vpn point to sit from client to azure virtual network

no i have 2 versions 64bit and 32bit vpn client package

the question is how to get url of file for downloading

Thanks everyone,
Quyen Pham

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can without using the api. When you click download from the portal it will dynamically generate a new file with a 1D expiration date. Anyway, all you need is to download the package, which is the same for everyone, and distribute this file and the proper certificate to your users.

Comment: Hi Bruno Faria, i reading from microsoft. it is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn205126.aspx - Generate VPN Client Package
in remark has sentence : If Status in the response from Get Virtual Network Gateway Operation Status is Succeeded, then Data in the response contains the Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL to the VPN client package

i think that if get the url of file, we can download the file by programming, but when i applied code api rest, status code of funtion generate is accepted not created :(

Comment: double check your request body and headers.